# Rails / jQuery: How would I force a full page refresh on "Ctrl + R"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a single page checkout for a ecommerce store, and I have 2 parts, one to save the billing info through AJAX (through the "Review" button), and the other to submit the order "Submit order".

When a user first lands on the page, the "Edit" and "Submit order" buttons are disabled.
When the user presses "Review", it disables all the inputs from "Review" and up, and enables "Submit order" as seen below:

[good http://imageshack.com/a/img856/2023/8rtf.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img856/2023/8rtf.png)

However, at this point when I press "Ctrl + R", the form's inputs' initial state is not the same as described before. The top is disabled, and for some odd reason makes my credit card fields enabled:

[bad http://imageshack.com/a/img841/7120/povo.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img841/7120/povo.png)

Does anyone know how I would force a full page refresh when this particular page is loaded?
I'm using Rails + jQuery.

Comment: Do you mean "When i reload the page, some of my form fields are filled in already"?  If so then this is the browser trying to helpfully autocomplete your fields.  Try adding (in the markup) an attribute of `autocomplete='off'` to your fields.

Comment: No, after filling out the form and pressing "Review" (like in the first picture), when I go to the URL and press enter, the form resets and becomes completely empty (which is the same behavior I want for when the user presses ctrl + r)

Comment: Can you add (in an edit to your question) the js that's called when you click the Review button?

Comment: hey Max I figured it out

Answer (score 0):

So I looked it up and found an answer. In the controller action I added a before_filter to change the response headers so that nothing is cached:

```
    class CheckoutsController < ApplicationController

      before_filter :set_cache_headers, only: [:billing]

      private

        def set_cache_headers
          response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store"
        end

    end
```